# Hide rows of a section in a tableview on tap

Tags: swift, tableview

What is the best way to show and hide rows related to a section on tap?

I have a table view with multiple sections and populated with data

I want to hide the rows when the user press on the section

What is the best practice to achieve that?

Comment: Expandable Tableviews ?

Comment: set tableview row height 0 and 44(for example) depend on open/close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is maybe the answer to your question. (you can expand and collapse the height of a cell)

[Swift: How to animate the rowHeight of a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626282/swift-how-to-animate-the-rowheight-of-a-uitableview)